# Only show data for a determined duration with php

Tags: php, mysql, duration

I have a page that shows posts stored in a mysql database. When the post is created the user can select how long they want the post to be visible for and I'm trying to figure how to only show posts for a determined duration. Here is some of my code (that hopefully shows the logic I'm trying).

```
//Query database

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `posts`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db_connection->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db_connection->error . ']');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    //The date the post was made
    $date_of_post = $row['date_of_post'];
    //The duration of the post in days eg 7.
    $duration = $row['duration'];
   //Attempting to add duration to date
    $newdate = strtotime($duration, $date_of_post);
    //Only show posts that are still valid, eg date + duration is less than today's date
    if($newdate > now()){
        echo '<h2>Post Title</h2>';
        echo '<p>Date of Posted:'.$date.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: _When the post is created the user can select how long they want the post to be visible_ So how do you store this information

Comment: use a `WHERE` clause for one.

Comment: And Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's just stored in a var char column as a number in the database. Like 7 for 7 days

Comment: Well there is your first mistake, well I hope its your first. Store dates in a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column type and then you can easily use them in queries

Comment: Then you can do as @FunkFortyNiner suggests and add a where clause without having to do a lot of type conversion before the date is any use to you

Comment: But it's a duration, not a date. The date of the posts are stored in date columns.

Comment: Ok thanks. I shall try and do this with the query.

Comment: Well where is that mentioned in your question. Lets see a schema of this table

Comment: Hint: use `date_add` to add the `duration` (converted to int) to the `date_of_post`, and compare it against `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `where` clause and a `date_add` function to apply this filter directly in your SQL query. Simply add the `duration` days to the `date_of_post` value, and compare it against `NOW()`.

Note that because you're storing your `duration` value as a varchar instead of an int, you'll need to `convert` the duration value to a `signed int`.

Here is an example, with the `date_add` expanded out to make it clearer to understand what is happening.

```
select
    *
from
    posts
where
    date_add
    (
        date_of_post,
        INTERVAL convert(duration, SIGNED INT) DAY
    ) > NOW()
```

As a side note, you should always try to filter your data in your query, and not in your PHP script. Don't just select your entire table into your script - let SQL do as much work as possible. The RDBMS is far more efficient than PHP, and you'll save a lot on overhead (eg amount of data sent over the network, and how much RAM has to be used to store the results for PHP to work with, etc).